# One column full width of page

Tags: html, css

I have searched everywhere for an answer and couldn't find it anywhere. Here's the issue. I have a website with one column two rows. The first row in transparent with a image set as the background. The second row below the first is a bright solid fill color/texture overlapping the first. The problem I am having is on the very right and left of the second column I can slightly see a border/space with the background image showing from behind. My question is how can I get the second column to sit flush on the window from edge to edge so that you can't see the back?

```
<p>
  <span style="font-family: Impact; font-size: 72px; font-weight: normal;"><br></span>
</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
  <span style="font-family: Impact; font-size: 72px; font-weight: normal; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-shadow: rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.808594) 0px -1.4px 0px;"><br></span>
</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
  <span style="font-family: Impact; font-size: 72px; font-weight: normal; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-shadow: rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.808594) 0px -1.4px 0px;">Little About Me</span>
</p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
```

Comment: A codepen or js bin would help, but it is most likely because you haven't reset your padding/margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `body{margin:0}` to your CSS.